# How to write a Python nested "for" loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, loops, for-loop

I hope this is descriptive enough,

could anyone show me how to write this python code in javascript?

I am in week 3 in javascript school and I had this python syntax in some code I wrote about a year ago.

I am just curious how I would go about writing this in javaScript.

I feel like this would greatly help me understand nested for loops in JS!

```
for Row in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]:
  for Fixture in range(5):
    for Shelf in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]:
      for Bin in range(4):
        print(f"{Row } {Fixture + 1} {Shelf} {Bin + 1}")
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Javascript's loop syntax is pretty similar to Python's, and looping is covered in _every_ tutorial out there. Have you tried anything in JS? If not, please make an attempt and [edit] your question to be more specific. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and provide a [mre] _of the problem you're having_. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple short terms it's

```js
for ( const Row of [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] ) {

    for ( let Fixture = 0; Fixture < 5; Fixture++ ) {

        for ( const Shelf of [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" ] ) {

            for ( let Bin = 0; Bin < 4; Bin++ ) {

                // used to print in this demo
                document.write( `${Row } ${Fixture + 1} ${Shelf} ${Bin + 1}` );
                document.write("</br>");

                // you can also log to a console
                console.log(`${Row } ${Fixture + 1} ${Shelf} ${Bin + 1}`);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this JS I used 2 different types of loops to get this result.

The first loop is a `for of` loop. It takes the objects directly from the Array.

The second loop has a setting point that runs before the loop `let Fixture = 0;`, the second part is the conditional part to check if the loop should keep going `Fixture < 5;`, and the final part is executed after each loop run `Fixture++` to add to the number.

A other common way of looping arrays is to use the ES6

I'd strongly recommend checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration to read more about loops in javascript.

Comment: This absolutely accomplishes the same thing as well! Thank you for the descriptive answer. Trevor.

Comment: I am unfamiliar what the backticks ` and the $ signs represent though, are you able to explain that by chance?

Comment: @JosephKelly They are javascripts way of doing Template Literals much the same as you had varaibles in your string. In javascript you are required to use backticks instead of quotes and the dollar sign plus the {} brackets for the expression.

Comment: I understand, Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Row=["A","B", "C", "D", "E"];
Shelf=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"];

for(var i=0;i<Row.length;i++){
  for(var Fixture=0;Fixture<5;Fixture++){
    for(var k=0;k<Shelf.length;k++){
      for(var Bin=0;Bin<4;Bin++){
        console.log(Row[i]+" "+(Fixture+1)+" "+Shelf[k]+" "+(Bin+1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This absolutely accomplishes the exact same thing thank you Priyankarao

Comment: You are welcome! :) Sorry for not using the exact variable names